# How to calculate R-Square and bound beta coefficients over zero at a time with SAS

Tags: sas, constraints, regression, bounds

I am not an English speaker, so first I am sorry for my English.

I am using SAS, and I want to calculate R-Square and bound beta coefficients over zero at a time.

I've tried and searched several procedures such as PROC MODEL OR PROC REG.

However, according to a SAS community, only 'BOUNDS' can be used with PROC MODEL but not RSQ and only equation restriction can be used with PROC REG.

Is there some way to solve it at a time? Thank you.